# Why can't I construct a gsl::span with a brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, cpp-core-guidelines

According to the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), I should [use a gsl::span to pass a half-open sequence](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rf-range).

I think that means that instead of writing a function like:

```
void func(const std::vector<int>& data) {
    for (auto v : data) std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

I should prefer:

```
void func(gsl::span<const int> data) {
    for (auto v : data) std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Which has the advantage that it does not assume the caller has their data in a `vector`, or force them to construct a temporary `vector`. They could pass a `std::array` for example.

But a common use-case is to pass a brace-enclosed initializer list:

```
func({0,1,2,3})
```

This works for a function taking a `std::vector` but for a function taking a `gsl::span` I get the error message:

> error C2664: 'void func(gsl::span)' : cannot convert
>   argument 1 from 'initializer-list' to 'gsl::span'

It looks like `gsl::span` [has a templated constructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/span.h) designed to take any container.

Is this just something missing from the Microsoft GSL implementation or is there a good reason to prevent this practice?

Comment: A braced list isn't a container.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is a `std::initializer_list` a container?

Comment: No, it isn't. It's a language-support type to represent initializer lists... But even if it were, that wouldn't help, because your argument isn't of type `std::initializer_list<int>`. It's just a braced list.

Comment: @KerrekSB OK, then mentioning the templated constructor taking a container is a bit of a distraction. But my question still stands.

Comment: Well, the answer is that no suitable constructor is provided by `gsl::span`...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you call the vector version, the initializer list is used to create a temporary `std::vector`, which is then passed to the function by const reference. This is possible, because `std::vector` has a constructor, that takes an `std::initializer_list<T>` as an argument.
However, `gsl::span` doesn't have such a constructor and as `{0,1,2,3}` doesn't have a type, it also can't be accepted by the templated constructor you mentioned (besides the fact, that `std::initializer_list<T>` wouldn't satisfy the container concept anyway).

One (ugly) workaround would be of course to explicitly create a temporary array:

```
func(std::array<int,4>{ 0,1,2,3 });
```

I don't see a particular reason, why `gsl::span` should not have a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`, but keep in mind that this library is in still pretty new and under active development. So maybe it is something they overlooked, didn't have time to implement, weren't sure how to do properly or there are really some details, that would make that construct dangerous. Its probably best to ask the developers directly on github.

---

EDIT:
As @Nicol Bolas explains in his comment, this was [by design](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues/137) because an initializer list like `{0,1,2,3}` (and the elements within) is a temporary object and as `gsl::span` is not a container in its own right (it doesn't take ownership of the elements), they think it would be too easy to accidentally create a `gsl::span` that contains a dangling reference to those temporary elements.

So, while this would be OK:

```
func({ 0,1,2,3 });
```

because the lifetime of the initializer list ends after the completion of the function, something like this would create a dangling reference:

```
gsl::span<const int> data{ 0,1,2,3 };
func(data);
```

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thank you, I added this to my answer. Maybe you can have a look, whether the edit is correct.

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic idea.

Comment: Note your "fix" example doesn't work, and also it should be 4 not 3 int the std:::array.  See this: https://godbolt.org/z/zj7nGa and https://godbolt.org/z/Tv7eMY

Comment: @whn: Thanks! You are right about the array size of course(fixed that), but `func` takes a `span<const int>` for which that code works and not a `span<int>` as in your godbolt links.

Comment: @MikeMB Ah I didn't realize const would have any different behavior, that indeed fixes it.  https://godbolt.org/z/fTqqzn

Comment: @MikeMB: Consider https://godbolt.org/z/aozvad61n ; I don't understand why explicitly specifying `initializer_list` really helps, but it does.  Additionally, it seems that a few things evolved since your answer was posted: in the godbolt above, we can see that C++ allows for dangling span references (the vector at the bottom).  Can you elaborate on these changes?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Span is non owning.  Does not own storage.  It is a replacement for pointer arithmetic, not a storage class.

You need to put your data in a storage class, and then if you want to do clever things with pointer arithmetic, you instead do clever things with spans.

You cannot initialize a span with an initializer list, because there is nowhere to put the data.

Answer (score 1):

This now works with `absl::Span`.  The following example is copied from https://abseil.io/tips/93:

```
void TakesSpan(absl::Span<const int> ints);

void PassALiteral() {
  // Span does not need a temporary allocation and copy, so it is faster.
  TakesSpan({1, 2, 3});
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning the [warnings from it's source](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/blob/master/absl/types/span.h#L254)