# How to accept both std::vector and std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++17

I have

```
void f(std::initializer_list<int> x);
// .cpp
void f(std::initializer_list<int> x) { /* Lots of code */ }
```

At some moment I need also

```
inline void f(std::vector<int> x) { /* I want call f(initializer_list), but cant */; }
```

My solution

```
void f_inner(const int* x, std::size_t size);
inline void f(std::initializer_list<int> x) { f_inner(x.begin(), x.size(); } 
inline void f(std::vector<int> x) { f_inner(x.data(), x.size()); }
// .cpp
void f_inner(const int* x, std::size_t size) { /* Lots of code */ }
```

Maybe there's a more elegant solution? But I don't want to move f_inner to .h and make it a template

Comment: You don't really need the `std::initializer_list` overload. Just stick with `const std::vector<int>&` and that will cover your use-cases. If you would like to have the option of not allocating dynamically with the `std::initializer_list`, then the solution you have is good.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't think about it :)

Comment: What don't you like about your solution? If anything, I'd move `f_inner` to the .cpp - but otherwise it does what you want well, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a type like gsl span.

Both vector and initializer lists are contiguous containers, and a span to const data can wrap either at zero cost.

So you can throw one together that solves your problem cleanly.  GSL span itself blocks it out of a misguided attempt to defend itself against dangling local spans constructed with ils.

Comment: a span cannot wrap an initializer_list! that would be very dangerous wrt lifetime/dangling. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874772/why-cant-i-construct-a-gslspan-with-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-list

Comment: correction, a span can be explicitly constructed from an initializer_list, e.g. `void foo(std::span<int>); foo( std::initializer_list<int>{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42} );` works, but `foo( {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42} );` does not because a braced init-list alone has no type and there's no ctor taking initializer_list to coerce it. see e.g. https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/10/03/p2447-span-from-initializer-list/ and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2447r1.html