# shorthand std::array literal parameter

Tags: c++, c++17, stdarray

I've been trying to write some shorter code that still uses std::array but I'm not sure how to get the deduction to work in my favor.

Is there a way to write this that is equally as short(readable) as the vector version?

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <std::size_t SIZE>
void afunc(const std::array<std::string_view, SIZE> &v)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << v[rand()%SIZE];
    }
}

void vfunc(const std::vector<std::string_view> &v)
{
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << v[rand()%v.size()];
    }
}

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

int main()
{
  std::array<std::string_view, 2> works = {"1","2"};
  afunc(works);// verbose
  //afunc({ "1","2" }); // 1st  fail
  //afunc({ "1"sv,"2"sv }); // 2nd fail
  //afunc(std::array{ "3","4" });// 3rd fail
  afunc(std::array{ "3"sv,"4"sv, "test"sv,"other"sv });// works but verbose

  vfunc({"5","6", "7"});// vectors are easy to code with

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` and `std::vector` have the same `size()` and `operator[]` members, so you could roll your 2 functions into 1 function:

```cpp
template <typename Container>
void func(const Container &c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << c[rand() % c.size()];
    }
}
```

```cpp
std::array<std::string_view, 2> a{"1","2"};
func(a);

std::vector<std::string_view> v{"1","2"};
func(v);

func<std::array<std::string_view, 2>>({"1","2"});

func<std::vector<std::string_view>>({"1","2"});
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/o6c4Tx)

But, as you can see, that can be too verbose for your taste.  But, you can support braced lists as a parameter *without* having to specify the template argument explicitly, by defining an extra function that accepts `std::initializer_list` as a parameter, and then the compiler can deduce that parameter for you.

But, `std::initializer_list` doesn't have `operator[]`, so you would have to change your main function logic to use random-access iterators instead, if you intend to share common code between the functions, eg:

```cpp
template <typename Iter>
void func(Iter begin, Iter end, std::random_access_iterator_tag)
{
    size_t size = end - begin;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << *(begin + (std::rand() % size));
    }
}

template <typename Iter>
void func(Iter begin, Iter end)
{
    func(begin, end,
      typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::iterator_category());
}

template <typename Container>
void func(const Container &c)
{
    func(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
}

template <typename T>
void func(const std::initializer_list<T> &l)
{
    func(l.begin(), l.end());
}
```

```cpp
std::array<std::string_view, 2> a{"1","2"};
func(a);

std::vector<std::string_view> v{"1","2"};
func(v);

func({"1"sv, "2"sv});
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/a8FkOG)

Comment: I think the trouble with making the template completely generic is all the verbosity is at the call site, which some may see as good design. However if you have a private routine that is designed to increase the readability all the use cases within a file than all the call site verbosity is unwelcome. Your func also is not able to figure out that type is array or vector for the inline literal thus does not meet the criteria of the question.

Comment: "*Your func also is not able to figure out that type is array or vector for the inline literal*" - supporting `std::initializer_list` as a parameter eliminates the need to do that, as my 2nd example shows. Also, it is possible to specialize the function for just `std::array` or `std::vector`, if that is what you really want.

Comment: I see it now. Sorry. This actually works pretty good. Even if the metaprogramming would be cryptic to a beginner.

Comment: Would you expect the binary to be bigger this way?

Comment: Not considerably, but each instantiation of a template will be its own separate copy of the code in the executable, yes.  But that is what happens when you use templates.

Comment: C++ is such a crazy language especially when you get into the template programming side of it. While I really don't like how much this method changes the initial implementation of the routine, it does solve the issue of call site verbosity. However, I wouldn't wish this style of programming on my worst enemy. Imagine if the method was vastly more complex. The objective of the method is far less clear, however, if the routine is being used thousands of times this would be an improvement.

Comment: I mean in comparison to the other template methods, such as a c style array or std::array.

Comment: To make things even less clear, if a user happens to pass a std::list into func they will get a ridiculous error message since list does not have random access. So really the template programmer would need to put a contract/concept on the second and third template to clarify that the random iterator is required. Which amounts to way too much code for a very simple problem.

Comment: @Medran `static_assert` can validate and emit a human-readable error message on failure. For instance, you can fail more gracefully if the iterators are not random-access, without using tag dispatching like I did (or even with tag dispatching, just `static_assert(false)` in an overload that takes all other tag types). Technically, `std::list` *could* be used in this `func()`, if `size_t size = end - begin;` is changed to `size_t size = std::distance(begin, end);`, but the code just wouldn't run very efficiently with `std::list` iterators due to re-iterating the list over and over.

Comment: my point is that there is a real tradeoff in a C++ code base between method implementation clarity/shortness and call site clarity/shortness. Anyways, thanks for your answer, you are a stellar contributor on stack.

Answer (score 2):

You can't infer a compile-time size from an initializer list parameter, so you need to pass the size explicitly:

```cpp
template <std::size_t Size>
void afunc(const std::array<std::string_view, Size> &v)
{ ... }

int main()
{
    afunc<2>({ "1", "2" }); // ok
}
```

Your `vfunc` for `std::vector` doesn't need to deduce a compile-time size, which is why this limitation only applies to template argument deduction for `std::array` in `afunc`.

Comment: I've for sure thought about this, but having the template parameter does increase the code maintenance if the list changes.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to get C style arrays to work as an option. When I had tried this before my reference was not const thus would not compile with a temporary. Not as good as arrays for the lack of iterators but still straightforward

```
template<size_t N> 
 void carr_try(std::string_view const(&a)[N])
 { 
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[rand()%N];
    }
 }

// for illustrative purposes of how to NOT write this routine
 template<size_t N> 
 void nonconst(std::string_view (&a)[N]) 
 { 
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << a[rand()%N];
    }
 }


int main()
{
    carr_try({ "1", "2" }); // ok
//nonconst({"1","2"});// not ok
std::string_view temp[]={"3","4"};
nonconst(temp);// is fine but long
}
```

Comment: Both functions are using read-only access to the array, so there is no need for separate const and non-const functions, just use a single const function.  You can pass a non-const variable to a const parameter.

Comment: nonconst is there as an example of what doesn't work.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874772/why-cant-i-construct-a-gslspan-with-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-list
has some interesting stuff about trying to initialize a span with similar call site verbosity problems.

Comment: `std::begin(a)` and `std::end(a)`will give you the iterators you want for an array.