# No viable conversion from 'const VertexAttrib [2]' to 'std::span<VertexAttrib>'

Tags: c++, c++20

I thought `std::span` was basically built to accepts arrays or vectors, so I don't know why my function won't accept this array.

The function signature is:

```
void init(size_t size, const void *data, GLenum usage, std::span<VertexAttrib> attribs) const
```

Called with:

```
_vertices.init(4 * sizeof(ImageTexture2D),
                     vertices ? vertices->data() : nullptr,
                     vertices ? GL_STATIC_DRAW : GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW,
               TexturedVertex2D::attribs);
```

Where `TexturedVertex2D::attribs` is:

```
struct VertexAttrib {
    /** Number of components per generic vertex attribute */
    uint8_t dim;
    /** Data type of each component in the array */
    VertexAttribType type;
};

struct TexturedVertex2D {
    glm::vec2 pos;
    glm::vec2 tex;

    static constexpr VertexAttrib attribs[]{{2,VertexAttribType::Float}, {2,VertexAttribType::Float}};
};
```

The error from the compiler is:

> error C2664: 'void VertexArrayObject::init(size_t,const void *,GLenum,std::span<VertexAttrib,18446744073709551615>) const': cannot convert argument 4 from 'const VertexAttrib [2]' to 'std::span<VertexAttrib,18446744073709551615>'

How can I allow `init` to take contexpr arrays or inline-constructed arrays like that?

Comment: Looks like a constness issue. Try `std::span<const VertexAttrib>`?

Comment: @Ben That doesn't seem to work when called with `{{2,VertexAttribType::Float}}`: `error C2664: 'void VertexArrayObject::init(size_t,const void *,GLenum,std::span<const VertexAttrib,18446744073709551615>) const': cannot convert argument 4 from 'initializer list' to 'std::span<const VertexAttrib,18446744073709551615>'`

Comment: @mpen: It shouldn't work. You should not be able to take an initializer_list and turn it into a `span`.

Comment: Ya..reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/33883448/65387 now. Hmm..is there no elegant way to allow both?

Comment: Ok. I forget when it can implicitly convert. Try explicitly passing a span constructed with a pointer and size.

Comment: It's fine actually, I'll just declare it as an array above instead of trying to inline it as an initializer-list. Not quite as pretty but not bad. Thanks guys :)