# Construct static extent of std::span from `{pointer, length}`

Tags: c++, pointers, c++20

#### Preface

Given a `char *p` pointer pointing to a buffer with given `size_t length`. Caller will guarantee the buffer is valid.

I want to use `void spanStatic(std::span<char,8> s)` to modify the buffer.
I tried to use `spanStatic({p, length})` where `length` is larger than `8`.
The compilation failed. I presum compiler may not deduce initializer list to `span<char,8>`... but with `span<char,dynamic_extent>`?

Note: I tend to use static extent. Since the lengh I want to modified is decided in compile time and the issue may be found in compile time as well.

#### Question:

Is there a shorter way to construct a temporary span instead of using `spanStatic(std::span<char, 8>(p, length))`?

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qeK75vrfh)

```
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <span>

constexpr const char MAGIC_PATTERN[] = "\xBA""\xAD""\xF0""\x0D""\xDE""\xAD""\xBE""\xEF";
constexpr static size_t LEN = sizeof(MAGIC_PATTERN) - 1;

constexpr static std::span<const char, LEN> magic(MAGIC_PATTERN, LEN);

void spanDynamic(std::span<char> s){
    std::copy(magic.begin(), magic.end(), s.begin());
}
void spanStatic(std::span<char,LEN> s){
    std::copy(magic.begin(), magic.end(), s.begin());
}
int main()
{
    char data[] = "hello world";

    // Mimic a valid pointer + length, where length must be larger than LEN
    char* p = data;
    spanDynamic({p, LEN});
    // spanStatic({p, LEN}); // <--failed
}
```

#### Edit:

Thanks for [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75622997/4123703) and [HarryLeong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3059809/harryleong)'s comment.
It's intended to have explicit constructors.
My final solution is `using MySpan = std::span<char, 8>`.

---

This question is different from [Why can't I construct a gsl::span with a brace-enclosed initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874772/why-cant-i-construct-a-gslspan-with-a-brace-enclosed-initializer-list) which is constructing a temporary `std::array` to a span.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`span` was explicitly designed to not allow you to do that. If you're using a `span` with a compile-time fixed size, the type was written so that you *have to* spell out that fixed size when you try to create one. That way, it's abundantly clear to everyone what the actual size is, even though you passed `length`.

Comment: I think you are right. This is [the standard committee decision](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1976r1.html) I just found.